# Passing a custom function in BLME r package via rpy2 in python

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Issue: In Python, I am trying to pass a `dnorm()` R function to the argument `cov.prior` of the R package called [Blme](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/blme/blme.pdf). The example is written on page 4 for the custom prior. I wanted to use Gaussian as my covariance prior distribution, but I don't know how to wrap the `dnorm()` function with the `custom()` in order to make it work.

Here is my attempt 1

```
from rpy2 import robjects 
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

stats = importr("stats")
blme = importr("blme")
lmc = robjects.r(f"lmerControl({control})")
dnorm = stats.dnorm
covprior = robjects.r(f"custom({dnorm})")
blme.blmer(formula, data=data, REML=REML, control=lmc, contrasts=contrasts, **{cov.prior=covprior})
```

Here is my attempt 2

```
from rpy2 import robjects 
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

stats = importr("stats")
blme = importr("blme")
lmc = robjects.r(f"lmerControl({control})")
robjects.r(''' penalityFn <- function(sigma){dnorm(sigma, 1, 1)}''')
covprior = robjects.r(f"custom({penalityFn})")
blme.blmer(formula, data=data, REML=REML, control=lmc, contrasts=contrasts, **{cov.prior=covprior})
```

Comment: This would wrap it `custom(dnorm)` in the way that you have asked. Although i dont know what `custom()` is as it is not defined anywhere in the code given.

Comment: I have two different ways. Which way? ```custom()``` is required by the package since ```dnorm``` can not be passed directly to ```cov.prior```. Both attempts throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
from rpy2 import robjects 
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
blme = importr("blme")
lmc = robjects.r(f"lmerControl({control})")
r_string = robjects.r("""penalityFn <- function(sigma){dnorm(sigma, 1, 1)}""")
covprior = ("custom(penalityFn)")
blme.blmer(formula, data=data, REML=REML, control=lmc, contrasts=contrasts, **{cov.prior=covprior})
```